# How do I do regex replacement with numbered groups?

Tags: regex

I'm trying to do a replace of all instances of strings like

```
PageLocalize("Texts", "R73")
```

with something like

```
Texts.R73.Localise()
```

I have a regex for matching these strings:

```
PageLocalize\("([A-Za-z]+)", "([A-Za-z0-9]{0,6})"\)
```

And a replacement string:

```
$1.$2.Localise()
```

but [The Regex Coach](http://www.weitz.de/regex-coach/) says my replacement result is

```
$1.$2.Localise()
```

What do I need to do to my regex to get the numbered groupings to work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I haven't used RegexCoach, but some Regex engines require you to specify a backreference with a backslash, like this :

```
\1.\2.Localise()
```

The result you are getting is only possible if $1 is not recognized as a backreference to Group 1.

**Edit:**

I just checked and [RegexCoach](http://www.weitz.de/regex-coach/) appears to use the Perl Regex syntax. If that is so, then `$1` would be a valid backreference to Group 1. Then it would seem that the engine is unable to match the groups.

Comment: Just wondering, if it's a valid backreference, how come it ends up in the result string?  I'd expect it to be replaced with an empty string at least.

Comment: +1 You're right about RegexCoach, it works if you use \1 instead of $1.  Turns out Regexcoach is not a .NET application!

Answer (score 2):

It works fine in a test application:

```
var r = new Regex(
    "PageLocalize\\(\"([A-Za-z]+)\", \"([A-Za-z0-9]{0,6})\"\\)");
var s = r.Replace("PageLocalize(\"Texts\", \"R73\")", "$1.$2.Localise()");
Console.WriteLine(s);
```

This results in:

```
Texts.R73.Localise()
```

AmitK found the correct way to do in in Regex Coach, which uses \1 instead of $1. It turns out that RegexCoach is not a .NET application, so it's not using the .NET regular expressions!

On a separate note, do you know about [named groups](http://www.knowdotnet.com/articles/regereplacementstrings.html)?  They're easier to maintain, especially if you add new groups to the regex. Can't get Stackoverflow to display a named group regex without spaces, so here it is with spaces in between:

( ? < group_name > yourregex )

And in the replacement text:

```
${group_name}
```